# Get button clicked Matlab imshow

Tags: matlab, imshow

I would like to get the position and which button is clicked in an axis were a image is loaded with imshow. At the moment I am using following

```
  h = imshow(template,[]);
  set(h,'ButtonDownFcn',@ImageClickCallback)
```

and then the function ImageClickCallback is

```
  axesHandle  = get(objectHandle,'Parent');
  coordinates = get(axesHandle,'CurrentPoint'); 
  coordinates = coordinates(1,1:2)
```

but I can't find any information about how to the get the clicked button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by button - you mean mouse button (left, right, middle) -

You need to get the Selection type of the parent figure:

```
hFig = ancestor ( 'axesHandle', 'figure );

get ( hFig, 'SelectionType')
```

where:

```
   'normal' = left button
   'extent' = middle button
   'alt'    = right button.
```